# Rails : Has_Many Through polymophic Could not find the association in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

I'm in front of a little problem, I try to have a polymophic has many through association :

## post.rb

> has_many :categories, as: :categorizable, through: :categorizations

## category.rb

> has_many :categorizables, through: :categorizations, dependent: :destroy

## event.rb

> has_many :categories, as: :categorizable, through: :categorizations

## categorization.rb

> belongs_to :categorizable, :polymorphic => true
>
> belongs_to :category

## My migration :

> def change
>
> ```
> create_table :categories do |t|
>   t.string :name
>
>   t.timestamps
> end
>
> create_table :categorizations do |t|
>   t.references :category
>
>   t.integer :categorizable_id, :polymorphic => true
>   t.string :categorizable_type, :polymorphic => true
>
>   t.datetime :created_at
> end
>
> add_index :categorizations, :category_id
> ```
>
> end

## the problem :

I got this error :

> Could not find the association :categorizations in model Post

Or when I try in category

> Could not find the association :categorizations in model Category

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: What is the problem? Any errors?

Comment: Scuse me ! I edit my question !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `:categorizations` association also, in `Category`, `Post` and `Event`. Also, your `as` option should go to `categorizations` association, since this is where you have polymorphism.

`Post` class:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations, as: :categorizable
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
  # ...
end
```

You should modify `Event` class in similar manner.

`Category` class:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categorizables, through: :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  # ...
end
```